# Regex for US Federal Tax ID (EIN)

Tags: html, regex

In the pattern attribute of an input tag, I am using the following regular expression for validation of the US Federal Tax ID field.

```
pattern="^([07][1-7]|1[0-6]|2[0-7]|[35][0-9]|[468][0-8]|9[0-589])-?\d{7}$"
```

But this regex allows 11-1111111, 22-2222222 (all same digits) type of entries. This type of entry should not be allowed. Please help with the correct regex.

Comment: In order for us to provide a valid regex, you'll need to provide us with a few values that **should** be accepted, and a few values that **shouldn't** be accepted.

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_Identification_Number) page on the topic, there are only restrictions on the first two numbers.

Comment: Hello Obsidian, Invalid entries would be 1) all digits are same(Example: 11-1111111, 22-2222222.. 99-9999999) 2) incremented digits(Example: 12-3456789) 3) first section 00 is not allowed (Example 00-XXXXXXX). Except these invalid entries, rest of the entries should be valid.

Answer (score 4):

Tim linked to the [format description](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_Identification_Number#EIN_format) of Federal Tax Identification Numbers (EINs) which says that the first two numbers can be any of 83 numbers. The remaining numbers can be anything. It would therefore, in fact, be easier to make a negative pattern that catches 07, 08, 09, 17, 18, 19, 28, 29, 49, 69, 70, 78, 79, 89, 96, 97:

```
^(?![01][789]|2[89]|[46]9|7[089]|89|9[67])\d\d-\d{7}$
```

But this doesn't catch EINs like `11-1111111` or `22-2222222`: You presumably want to catch these because it resembles the type of pattern that people flood-fill the form field with. You can catch repeated patterns like this:

```
^(\d)\1-\1{7}$
```

But becareful here: You cannot be sure that they're not valid. Every single of `11-1111111`, `22-2222222`, `33-3333333`, etc. are valid according to the definition (since 11, 22, 33, etc.) are all valid compus code prefixes.

So you'll eventually deny someone access whose EIN is legitimate.

The drawback of having a whitelist of EIN prefixes is that your software now has an external dependency on a list of numbers, and your package manager will not notify you about when legislation changes. Since it is very hard to predict the lifetime of software, this program might eventually deny EINs that are valid in the future. You'll have to weigh some costs here; making a really short regex is perhaps not the best thing you can achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little Python script I used to do the same:

```py
import re

pattern_tin = re.compile(r"^((?!12-3456789)(?!00-[0-9]{7})([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}))*$")
pattern_char = re.compile(r"^([0-9])\1*$")

user_input = input("Input a tax id: ")
if len(user_input) == 10 and re.fullmatch(pattern_tin, user_input): 
    work = user_input.replace('-', '')
    if not re.fullmatch(pattern_char, work):
        print("Valid entry")
    else:
        print("Invalid characters")
else: 
    print("Invalid entry")
```

Answer (score -2):

I have written a regex which satisfy the requirements.

```
pattern="^((?!11-1111111)(?!22-2222222)(?!33-3333333)(?!44-4444444)(?!55-5555555)(?!66-6666666)(?!77-7777777)(?!88-8888888)(?!99-9999999)(?!12-3456789)(?!00-[0-9]{7})([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}))*$"
```

Though it is not an efficient one. Anyone has more efficient regex?