# Regex for Custom Masked Field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Masked field that should of following format:

1. Can contain only Numeric Characters.
2. Can only contain a single dash.
3. The dash can only be in between some Numeric characters.

For example: 123-1232131 is a valid input while -1233123, 12-1231-123, 13123-, lasjd-12312 are all invalid.

So far I have tried building a regex as follows but it fails:

```
var input = $("#maskedInpTxt").val();

if(input.match(/[^0-9\-]/g))){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

However, this fails on the case `123123-132123-121`.

Comment: Try `^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for US Federal Tax ID (EIN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788168/regex-for-us-federal-tax-id-ein)